# What happens if I succumb to demonic temptation?

Tags: brogue

At one point in *Brogue*, I decided to run in a northwesterly direction (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Num7</kbd>). To my surprise, instead of running in that direction, the following message was delivered:

> A dark presence surrounds you, whispering promises of stolen power. Succumb to demonic temptation? (y/n)

I've said No, to which,

> The evil dissipates, hissing, from the air around you.

This was exceptionally unexpected, but it's also made me vastly curious. While I turned down the offer, I can bring it up again at any time by pressing the same key combination, to get the same promises and the same choice. This key choice isn't listed in the in-game help as far as I saw, so it's never quite explained what it does.

**What happens if I do what appears to be selling my soul to demons?** What is the benefits, the stolen power I receive? And what, naturally, is the catch, the drawback of doing so?

Comment: This reminds me quite a bit of the warning you get when you enable "wizard mode" in Angband.  Generally this means you can cheat, but your character is permanently marked as a cheater and can therefore not set high scores.  No idea if this is related, but I'll throw this thought out there anyhow.

Comment: The stolen power of travel in a diagonal direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This <kbd>Shift-Num7</kbd> combination only works when <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> is off - so what you're really pressing is <kbd>Shift-7</kbd> — the ampersand symbol on some keyboard layouts.

Anyway, the current version of the game explains the prompt by saying:

> Succumb to demonic temptation (i.e. enable easy mode)?

Answering <kbd>Y</kbd>es gives:

> An ancient and terrible evil burrows into your willing flesh! **--MORE--**
>   Wracked by spasms, your body contorts into an ALL-POWERFUL AMPERSAND!!!
>   You have a feeling that you will take 20% as much damage from now on.
>   But great power comes at a great price -- specifically, a 90% income tax rate.

It should be said that easy mode does not reduce the *gold* you find in the dungeon, but *your final score.*

Comment: Shift+7 = &, y'know. Which is the kind of demon you become. Intriguing. It's like a lower-level version of wizard mode - the benefits of trying the game without the high risk of death, but at the cost of your score.

Comment: @GraceNote Shift-7 is `/` on the Italian keyboard layout :)

Comment: Shift + 7 with or without NumLock doesn't give me the ampersand (or any character); I thought Windows (or any OS) interprets the numeric pad keys differently than the others.

Comment: @Nick Shift-7, not Shift-Num7

Comment: I misspoke.  Did OP mean 7, not Num7 then?  I don't understand the reason for your first paragraph

Comment: @NickT They both do the same thing if Num Lock is off. I imagine that Shift-Num7's behaving like Shift-7 with num lock off rather than Shift-Home is really an *cough* accidental feature *cough*